# Adding dependent project's properties file to the build target folder in Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm new to Maven, have looked for some help with my problem but couldn't find a proper solution.

I have a main project in Maven, which has a dependency to my second project:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>a.b.c</groupId>
   <artifactId>childproject</artifactId>
   <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Both projects have their properties files: mainproject.properties, childproject.properties.

When I deploy the main project, childproject.jar goes to \lib folder, along with all other dependencies. But the childproject.properties is "build into" the childproject.jar. If I place another childproject.properties file next to mainproject.properties in \configuration folder, it is seen and used.

What could I do so Maven places childproject.properties automatically in the \configuration folder?

Answer (score 0):

childproject.properties

1. pom mainproject has :

   ```
    <dependency>
       <groupId>a.b.c</groupId>
       <artifactId>childproject</artifactId>
       <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
   ```

   And add file in :

   ```
    mainproject
         /src/main/resources/mainproject.properties
   ```
2. childproject , add file in:

   ```
    childproject
         /src/main/resources/childproject.properties
   ```
3. When you deploy the main project => childproject.jar contain in classpath childproject.properties

You do not need to create a directory 'configuration' for the project 'mainproject' uses 'childproject.properties'.